# How to dynamically form a String based on Input

Tags: javascript

I have a symbol (@) seperated variable as shown below

```
var inputStr  = "IceCreams@Cone";
```

How can i split this and form a string in java script variable .

With the above input String how can  form a string as

**Are You Sure to add a Category Under IceCreams => Cone**

I have  tried as shown below ,but couldn't achive that dynamically

Thanks in advance .

```
function myFunction(inputStr) 
{
var res = inputStr.split('@');
var r = confirm("Are You Sure to add a Category Under" +res[0]+" "+res[1]+" );
    if (r == true) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4km0k9nv/1/

Comment: How is your method not dynamic?

Comment: check `inputStr`. e.g. `alert(inputStr);`

Comment: Probably just a typo, but you have an open `"` at the end of the string.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to transform "IceCreams" string into a variable with name IceCreams ?

Comment: @lzzey , sorry i didn't put my fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/4km0k9nv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works if you fix your typo.

```js
window.onload = function() {

    function myFunction(inputStr) {
        var res = inputStr.split('@');
        alert("Are You Sure to add a Category Under " + res[0] + " " + res[1] + " ?" );

    }
myFunction("Ice@cream");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,this was my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4km0k9nv/1/ , could you please tell me why its throwing an error in console as Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: For once, you never saved the split result. Only its length: `var size =inputStr.split('@').length;`. I made some other changes and the following works: http://jsfiddle.net/4km0k9nv/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the "@" symbol, you can use the string replace function.

```
var str = "part1@part2";
var str2 = str.replace('@', " => ");
```

Your example should work fine, but it seems to be a typo.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with it and I came up with this.  Is this what you want?  It runs the function on the input element blur.

```js
function myFunction(inputStr) 
{
var res = inputStr.split('@');
confirm("Are You Sure to add a Category Under " + res[0] + " => " + res[1] + " ?");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction(this.value)">
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(inputStr) 
{
var res = inputStr.split('@');
var r = confirm("Are You Sure to add a Category Under " + res[0] + " => "+ res[1] + "?");
    if (r == true) {
        addNewCategory(res[0], res[1]); // rename/rewrite this call as needed
    } else {
        cancelAdd(); // replace this line with whatever you need.
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can say:

```
var res = inputStr.replace("@", " => ");
var r = confirm("Are You Sure to add a Category Under " + res + "?");
```

The second bit of code would make `res` a string instead of an array of strings. Depending on your needs, that may suffice. If you'd like to or need to use `res` as an array of strings, then the first chunk of code should be all your need.